# How can I redirect user to another page when he clicks on alert box in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, click, alert

```
const logout = () => {
    axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/doLogout',
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        alert(response.data);
    })
    window.localStorage.removeItem("token");
    history.push('/HomePage')
}
return ( <
    div >
    <
    div className = "container-fluid" >
    <
    div className = "row" >
    <
    div className = "col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
    <
    /div> <
    div className = "col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
    <
    button type = "button"
    className = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    onClick = {
        () => logout()
    } >
    Logout < /button> <
    /div> <
    div className = "col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-5" >
    <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    /div>
);
}
```

**I am trying to redirect user to home page on button click by using history.push method can anyone tell me right approach to redirect user.I also tried Redirect method from react router but that also dosen't seems to work**

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with react. To me, it seems that issue is with the history.push call. According to the history API, it doesn't exist. See here: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/. Also, note that onClick={() => logout()} can be changed to onClick={logout}.

Comment: So can you  suggest any another way by which I can redirect user?

Comment: Check the history API. Your basic idea is good. The problem is that you are calling a non existing method.  Replace history.push('/HomePage') with history.pushState(null, null, '/HomePage') and it should work.

Comment: history.pushState give type error unhandled exception. Any other solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put it inside the `.then` block

```
   then((response) => {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("token");
        alert(response.data)
        history.push('/HomePage')
    })
```

or chain another `.then` on the end